# How can merge list value in a single list?

Tags: python

I have many files in a folder. I want to pick the latest file.
I have written code also, but it is givving values in separate list.

Output I'm getting:

```
['tb_exec_ns_decile_20190129']
['tb_exec_ns_decile_20190229']
['tb_exec_ns_decile_20190329']
```

Expected Output:

```
['tb_exec_ns_decile_20190129', 'tb_exec_ns_decile_20190229', 'tb_exec_ns_decile_20190329']
```

Code:

```
path1 = "D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/testing/*.csv"
files = glob.glob(path1)
print(files)

for name in files:
    new_files = []
    new_files = os.path.split(name)[1].split('.')[0]
    new_files = new_files.split(',')
    print(new_files)
```

Comment: creating `new_files = []` within every iteration, BAAAD!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct term here would be `append` not `merge` since, you want all the file names in a list together, Create an empty list to store all the file names in it:

```
f_list = []                              # an empty list to store the file names
for name in files:
    file_name = os.path.split(name)[1].split('.')[0]
    f_list.append(file_name.split(','))  # appending the names to the list

print(f_list)                            # print the list
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always merge list in python as in example below:

```
>>> first_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> second_list = [4, 5, 6]
>>> merged_list = first_list + second_list
>>> merged_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```